# Laravel как при неправильном вводе пароля вывести капчу при авиоризации?

Tags: laravel

Добрый день как при трех неудачных попытках авторизоваться вывести капчу. Капчу подключил, но не знаю как при неудачных попытках вывести капчу, знаю, что надо проверять ip, есть ли у кого примеры?

Comment: У вас доступ к гуглу пропал? :)

Comment: перерыл, но не нашел(

Answer (score 0):

Значит я вижу это так (если вы хотите велосипед писать сами )

1. Когда к вам заходит пользователь, у вас в любом случае записывается сессия

2)Когда пользователь вводит данные, вы валидируете их на приеме, и если он ввел их не правильно у вас есть метод hasError , при этом вы записываете число неудачных попыток у пользователя с этой сессией , (вы можете и ip отслеживать , это на ваше усмотрение , я бы записывал оба значения)

3. у вас есть индифицированный пользователь и количество не верных попыток, вы вставляете константу , при скольких попытках вам нужно Рендерить капчу и изменять условия валидации.

Логику я вижу так.